# File upload field not resetting after a successful submission in VueJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

In my VUeJS application I have a form to submit some data.

Once a user submits the form it should clear the existing field values.

But now when I submit the form it clears the all the fields except the file upload field.

If I uploaded a file called, dummy.pdf, it will display the dummy.pdf even after a successful submission.

Following is my code for the file upload field,

```
<div class="mb-1">
            <dashboard-input-label
              identifier="document"
              :settings="{ help: true, helpDirection: 'left' }"
            >
              Upload document
              <template slot="helpText">
                Maximum filesize is 5 MB. The default allowed file extensions
                are: pdf, jpeg and png.
              </template>
            </dashboard-input-label>
            <validator-v2
              :identifier="identifier"
              name="document_file"
              :rules="{ required: { message: 'Document is required.' } }"
            >
              <custom-file-upload
                ref="documentDocument"
                v-model="documentFile"
                :max-upload-file-size="5"
                name="document_file"
              ></custom-file-upload>
            </validator-v2>
          </div>
```

And my form button is,

```
<disables-submit-on-errors
            :identifier="identifier"
            @proceed="storeDocumentAndAddNew"
          >
            <loading-button ref="submitBtn" size="normal">
              Save & Add new
            </loading-button>
```

and under the methods, I have

```
storeDocumentAndAddNew() {
      this.isAddNew = true
      const loader = this.$refs.submitBtn
      this.storeDocument(loader)
    },

reset() {
      this.documentName= null
      this.dateOfIssue= null
      this.expiryDate= null
      this.documentNumber = null
      this.doesNotHaveDocumentNumber = false
      this.doesNotExpire = false
      this.documentFile = null
      this.doesOptIn = false
      this.isAddNew = false
    },
```

This will clear the name field, and the document number fields, but this won't clear the uploaded document's name...

What change I need to do clear all the fields after a successful submission?

Comment: share your `custom-file-upload`  component code.. are you using file input tag or anything else??

Comment: Your question is missing infos. Blind guess: try this.$refs.documentFile.value=null;

Answer (score 0):

To support v-model in components the component must implements a `value` prop and emit the `input` event.

It sound like the `value` prop is missing.

It kinda depends on the implementation of your `custom-file-upload` component, but here an example:

```
<template>
  <input @input="handleInput" :value="value" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  prop: ['value'],
  methods: {
    handleInput (e) {
      this.$emit('input', e)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```